# How to install swarms; AssertionError: Error: Could not open 'optimum/version.py' due [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'optimum/version.py'

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I'm trying to install swarms but I cannot and get this error:

```py
pip install swarms

Collecting swarms
  Using cached swarms-2.7.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (15 kB)
Collecting Pillow (from swarms)
  Using cached Pillow-10.1.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl.metadata (9.5 kB)
Collecting PyPDF2 (from swarms)
  Using cached pypdf2-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (232 kB)
Collecting accelerate (from swarms)
  Using cached accelerate-0.25.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (18 kB)
Collecting asyncio (from swarms)
...
Using cached optimum-0.1.1.tar.gz (17 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Using cached optimum-0.1.0.tar.gz (16 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [24 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'optimum/version.py'
      
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda/envs/tree_of_thoughts/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda/envs/tree_of_thoughts/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda/envs/tree_of_thoughts/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rn01vqif/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rn01vqif/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rn01vqif/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rn01vqif/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
      AssertionError: Error: Could not open 'optimum/version.py' due [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'optimum/version.py'
      
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

how to fix this issue?

cross: https://discord.com/channels/999382051935506503/1184252377356836954